# How to store the new ip address provisioned by Terraform?

Tags: javascript, node.js, terraform

I am performing cloud provisioning using terraform in ec2 instance, the provision is automated whereas the process starts once the front end sends a request to the backend.

And in the backend, which I have used is the node js, I am using the shell script and calling the commands for terraform

```
shell.exec('terraform init');
shell.exec('terraform plan -auto-approve');
shell.exec('terraform apply -auto-approve');
```

after this, cloud provision happens, but how to store that new instance IP somewhere in my backend?
let's say in MySQL?

the project folder structure is like the following:

```
Backend
|...
|
|-src
|    |_-index.js
|
|-terraform
|          |_main.tf
|
```

So, I am just looking for a way where I can get the new instance Ip from terraform back to the node js ?

Comment: You have not provided enough information to help you. What Cloud provider are you using? What resource do you need the IP from? Please add those details. This question cannot be answered as posed.

Comment: I want to extract the new instance IP from terraform to node js

Comment: At minimum, the resource block you want the IP from. The resource block will also tell folks answering your question what provider you are using, which is critical as the answer will vary significantly by provider.

Comment: As mentioned by @Alain, more info about the cloud provider architecture would have helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you need the IP address of the new EC2 instance provisioned after nodejs has completed the last step as per your shell script.
There are some required bits missing from your architecture based on which the solution may change, having an ASG, Public IPs attached, Cluster setup etc will require some changes in the solution.

I can suggest 2 options for you to explore. Use the Output block to

Option 1: Using tf output

The probable solution is using terraform output
https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/output.html

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami           = "${data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id}"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  tags = {
    Name = "HelloWorld"
  }
}
output "private_ip" { value = "${aws_instance.web.private_ip}" }
```

This will export the ip address of the EC2 instance and can be accessed after completion of the "tf apply" step using

```
shell.exec('terraform output private_ip');
```

Option 2:

Using data source "aws_instance"

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/instance.html

You can use this any time later to filter the available aws ec2 instances using tags/ids

This may not be the correct answer but will help you explore into other possible options.